# Настроить ssl на nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, dns

Здравствуйте!

Есть некий сервер, на котором nginx слушает один адрес (допустим, 1.1.1.1). Адрес резолвится в большую кучу dns-имён, при чём, самых разных. Допустим, у меня для каждого имени есть свой SSL-сертификат. Как мне настроить nginx, чтоб они для каждого имени ассоциировал свой сертификат?

Comment: `ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/${host}.pem;` Ну и сертификаты называть соответственно доменным именам. Для www можно скриптом сформировать символические ссылки или сформировать переменную с значением без www

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, у вас сервер имеет ip 1.1.1.1, на нем nginx и много dns указывают в A-записи на 1.1.1.1

Тогда так

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
server {
        listen     443;
        ssl        on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/site1.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/site1.key;

        server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
        root /var/www/site1;

        ...

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.com www.site2.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
server {
        listen     443;
        ssl        on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/site2.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/site2.key;

        server_name site2.com www.site2.com;
        root /var/www/site2;

        ...

}
```

Для каждого сайта сначала слушаем порт 80, делаем rewrite с http на https, потом слушаем 443.

Это выдержка из рабочего конфига nginx.

Comment: Ну вообще у меня в конфигах именно пара `IP:Port` , но я Вас понял, спасибо! Единственное, что меня огорчает, это то, что придётся делать миллиард секций server.

Comment: Ну, я уже давно при добавлении нового сайта дописываю секции server в конец конфига скриптом. Если ответ вас устроил, можно его отметить как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

насколько я помню можно конфиги для разных сайтов вынести из основного.  [ссылка](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=nginx&f=2)